# Symfony & Twig translate routing url by combining string with app.request

Tags: symfony, twig

I have added The following annotation routing to my controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/over-ons", name="_about-us_nl", defaults={"_locale": "nl"}, requirements={"_locale": "nl|en|de"})
 * @Route("/{_locale}/about-us", name="_about-us_en", defaults={"_locale": "en"}, requirements={"_locale": "nl|en|de"})
 * @Route("/{_locale}/uber-uns", name="_about-us_de", defaults={"_locale": "de"}, requirements={"_locale": "nl|en|de"})
 */
```

Now I want use the correct router in twig. But therefore I need to combine a string with an app.request. What is the syntax for this?

Following is not working:

```
{{ path( '_about-us_' ~ app.request.get('_locate') ) }}
```

Comment: Use `app.request.locale`

Comment: Are those annotations added on the same Controller method ?

Comment: Yes I have added them to one and the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) (check [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) the doc).

This bundle able you t o define your route as example:

<kbd>routing.yml</kbd>

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, de]
    strategy: prefix
```

Resulting URLs:

```
- /de/kontakt
- /en/contact
```

The bundle provide more knd of customization as described [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration#configuration)

The Bundle provide the correct URL without specify the locale. You can speficy the locale for generating the url:

```
<!-- uses locale of the request context to generate the route -->
<a href="{{ path("contact") }}">Contact</a>

<!-- sometimes it's necessary to generate routes for a locale other than that
     of the request context, then you can pass it explicitly -->
<a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "de"}) }}">Deutsch</a>
<a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "en"}) }}">English</a>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi Matteo, I already tried twice that bundle but I cannot get it working. Installation goes ok, but no routes are translates. The documentation about the usages of the bundle is very limited. So when I run the command to make the routing translation files my complete routing is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
{{ path('_about-us_', { '_locale': app.request.locale }) }}
```